# What is the meaning of "lots" in "in a fixed set of lots"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading a computer science algorithm paper and I wonder what "lots" means in the following context?

[image]

Comment: An amount or set of goods that is produced at the same time or sold together. In my country, eggs are often sold in lots of 6 or 12.

Comment: I think you would be better to ask a computer scientist/mathematician to be fair. I suspect it may have a specific meaning in those fields.  In ordinary language the noun"lot" just means a particular set or group of things/people.

Comment: @BillyKerr the words _buying, items,_ and _packaged_ suggest that the domain here is commerce, not mathematics.

Comment: @phoog I doubt it to be honest.

Comment: @BillyKerr the mathematical abstraction is _sets_ and _elements;_ the text gives an example of a real-world problem that they can be used to model, that of lots containing items that someone wants to obtain with a minimum of _buying._  The terms (those mentioned along with _obtain_ and _represent_) belong to this application of set theory for modeling a specific real-world domain, not to the mathematical realm of set theory itself.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, you may be right. I just couldn't get past the maths. LOL;)

Comment: @phoog is correct below, "lot" here is used to avoid speaking of "sets of sets", and also to indicate that the "lot" is available for selection or purchase as an indivisible group.  "Lot" ordinarily has no special meaning in mathematics.  (I am a computer scientist and mathematician.)  "Cover" does, but it's explained here.

Comment: If "lot" *doesn't* have a special meaning in maths, isn't it likely that the cited source would have defined what *they* wanted it to mean, on first use? Can we get access to the *full* source to check that possibility? Or is it possible to assume that ***which have been packaged in a fixed set of lots*** effectively "defines" the usage?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and type the relevant text into it. People using screen readers cannot read the text in images. Also, people generally cannot search for terms in images or copy-paste them.

Answer (score 3):

The sense used here is defined as [sense 5a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lot) by Merriam-Webster:

> a number of units of an article, a single article, or a parcel of articles offered as one item (as in an auction sale)

The mention of auctions is perhaps confusing, since auctions often concern unique items.  In the context of the problem, think of different collections of items that may appear in more than one collection.  For example, if someone sells portraits of British monarchs then a customer who buys the set *All the queens* and the set *All the monarchs whose names start with E* will have two portraits each of Elizabeth I and Elizabeth II.

Comment: Not always. Sometimes, to save time, auctioneers offer several items perceived as less valuable as a single lot, so if you want one of the items you have to buy them all.

Comment: @KateBunting what I meant was that the items in an auction are not typically fungible.  If there are two lots in an auction that both contain a portrait of Elizabeth II they are likely to be different portraits, rendering auction lots an inapt application of the principle of set cover.  The portraits I had in mind in my example are mass produced, so the duplicate portraits would be indistinguishable.  I started off thinking of action figures, but I didn't want to mention an actual commercial brand.